# Passing gridview's checkbox value to another webpage

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, gridview, checkbox

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with Visual Basic.  On my first webpage, I have a gridview with a button on each row that opens a new webpage and fills in the fields with values from the first webpage's gridview row where button clicked.  Works fine except for a field that's a checkbox.  It keeps passing false (or not checked) even if the checkbox is checked in the first pages's gridview's row.

On the original webpage,  I redirect the checkbox (I'll cut out the rest of the values that should have been where ... is) - Response.Redirect("TimeOffNoRequestEdit.aspx?... + "&AllDay_YesNo=" + row.Cells(3).Text.ToString() ...)

In the new webpage, the asp code for the checkbox is:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
```

On Page_Load of this new webpage, I am calling this value in with the following code:

```
CheckBox1.Text = Request.QueryString("AllDay_YesNo")
```

When I debug it, I'm always showing the checkbox as false, thus not checked.

I'd appreciate any help you can give me.  If you need me to post all my code, please let me know.  Thanks!

Comment: post the gridview markup and the rowdatabound from page 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're not accessing the value correctly. The current code, *row.Cells(3).Text.ToString()*, would fetch the text of a cell, but here the content we are looking for is a control, namely your checkbox.

I take for granted you provided the right cell index and this cell contains nothing but your checkbox. The idea here is you need to get the actual checkbox in order to reach the [Checked](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkbox.checked(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

```
Ctype(row.Cells[3].Controls[0], CheckBox).Checked.ToString()
```

Also, when you use the value on the second page, change your code to something along this line, because right now you are merely changing the checkbox's text:

```
CheckBox1.Checked = Boolean.Parse(Request.QueryString("AllDay_YesNo"))
```

Comment: Yeah!  It worked, but I still have something messed up.  I'm getting a checkbox with True (or False) next to it.  Do I have to change the code in the Page_Load - CheckBox1.Text = Request.QueryString("AllDay_YesNo")?  I don't know where to even figure out what to change it to.  (Long Day - brain dead)

Comment: I didnt realise this portion of the code contained a slight mistake too. You need to parse the string that represents the value, check my update.

Comment: Yes!!  Thanks so much RaNuD!  I'm going to post another question about these pages is a minute, and I'm sure you will know the answer right away!  I'm just learning asp, and I couldn't find a thing about passing values from a gridview other than text.  You rock!

Comment: My pleasure! If your question is answered, dont forget to mark it as such. It will be beneficial for me and your question wont pop in the "Unanswered questions" :)

Comment: Hi RaNuD!  This was working wonderfully until last week.  I started to have a problem with the code above.  I'm getting an error - The text, ntext, and image data types cannot be compared or sorted, except when using IS NULL or LIKE operator.   Any ideas, suggestions, ...  It was working!

Comment: It looks like you have changed the type of something, somewhere. Unfortunately there is not enough information for me to figure _what_ changed, I believe you will have to create another question containing the relevant information, i.e. is it a compilation error or a runtime exception, on what line, etc. Feel free to leave a link here, I will have a look at your new question when you post it.

Comment: did you enable sorting on the gridview since last week?

Comment: Thanks - got it to work with errors, so I'll create new questions.